# How can I add form action to this button?

Tags: html, css, button, redirect

Here is the HTML:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 33.3%;text-align: center;">
<button class="btntest btn-small-test btn-success-test">
<span class="icon-apply-test icon-white-test"></span>
Search Now</button>
</div>
```

I have tried using anchor text and form action, but nothing can add the onclick event.  How can I adjust this button so that when they click it the user is redirected to `google.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a form when you have javascript ;)

```
<button onclick="window.location='google.com'">Search google</button>
```

Comment: Yeah... for sure...  but this is the only way without form implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it inside a `form` and give it type `submit`.

A sample:

```
<form action="<target_url>" method="<get_or_post>">
  <button class="btntest btn-small-test btn-success-test" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like:

```
<form class="myForm" action="yourAction" method="post/get">
<input type="text"/> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the button needs to be inside a form that points to an action, like:

```
<form action="action_path" method="get">
 ...
</form>
```

Where action_path is a path to the action you want to send the data. There is, as you can see, a parameter for the action_type.

Then, when you put:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

It will trigger the form to send the data to the specifyed route .

Or you can just add and action (but in this case you dont need to necessarily use the button tag) using:

```
<anytag onClick='function() { js actions here }' >
```

So you can actually make your 'button' do anything by javascript.